# Not understanding when a user_token is required vs access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-group

I am having trouble understanding how FB determines if a user-token or an access_token is required.
I am not using Facebook for authentication in anyway, and really didn't want to.

I am trying to display information from our Facebook Group to our Forum.

According to the Graph API, /group-id/feed requires these:

- A user access token, for a member of the group, with user_groups permission is required.
- An app access token can read posts it published in app and game groups that belong to it.

/group-id/events requires only:

- A user access token for a member of the group with user_groups permission.

The text is slightly off, but look to me to be conveying the same thought about "user access token".

According to FB, in place of a user access token, it is possible to combine an app's app-id and app-secret to simulate an access_token.

When doing this for my group's feed, it works great.
When doing this for the events, I get an error that says:

- Code: 102
- Message: "A user access token is required to request this resource."
- Type: OAuthException

Why is the app-id|app-secret access_token not working?  I really don't want to worry about any FB authentication; I just wanted to list our events on our website.  Am I doing something wrong or missing the proper way to handle it?

```
$(function () {
    var location = document.URL;
    var ShowGroup = false;
    var group_id = null;

    if (location.indexOf("chattanooga-lodge") != -1) {
        group_id = "";
        ShowGroup = true;
    }

    if (ShowGroup) {
        $("#FBfeedContainer").show();
        // Initialize Facebook JavaScript API
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'app-id',
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.0'
            });

            //FB News Posts
            FB.api(
                "/" + group_id + "/feed",
                { access_token: "app-id|app-secret" },
                function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        $.each(response.data, function (index, data) {
                            if (index < 3) {
                                $("#FBfeed").append(data.id);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            );

            //FB Events
            FB.api(
                "/" + group_id + "/events",
                { access_token: "app-id|app-secret" },
                function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        $.each(response.data, function (index, data) {
                            if (index < 3) {
                                $("#FBfeed").append(data.id);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
        };

        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Combining an app's app-id and app-secret will create an app access token. Not a user access token. That is why the documentation say user access token and app access token.

Comment: And if you notice what I pasted from the API Documentation, that both the Feed AND Events say they require a user token.  As I also stated, the API Documentation says that you can use an app access token in place of a user access token.  Also, as I stated, in one case an app token works, in the other it doesn't.  *sigh* Did you read anything I posted?  I'm wondering why there are inconsistencies or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Where does it say you can use an app access token instead of a user access token? That is not correct. For `/{group-id}/events` the documentation you copied say it have to be a user access token. And for `/{group-id}/feed` the documentation you copied say that app access token can just access app and game groups. To access other groups you have to use a user access token that is member of that group and have given you user_group permission. And the error message you got say you have to use a user access token

Comment: App can access game groups that it belongs to.  But I created the app, my friend created the group and they are in no way linked together.  (Unless it's counting me as the owner of the app, and since I am part of the group, therefore a valid access token?

Comment: Sounds like a bug if an app access token works

Comment: Maybe it *is* a bug on the feed one then. and Events is the one that is acting properly.
I went back and looked at what I read about app-tokens and user-tokens...I totally misread it...lol.  But, even so, it made me do what I did, and it worked.  Strange things happen sometimes I guess.  This is the first time I've tried doing anything with FB API, so I'm a total noob.  Thanks for the help.  I have to agree, it must be a bug, or somehow the API is deriving a link because I'm the owner of the app, and I'm a member of the group, and causing that to be a valid token for the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to fetch a Group's events without using any user authentication. As you already pointed out about permissions mentioned for group-id/feed (requires either user access token or app access token) and group-id/events (requires user access token) endpoints. You are able to fetch feed data because of the App access token that you created by combining app id and app secret.

Each data point in Facebok API is strictly guarded by permissions. Some of them are public, others are accessed different type of access tokens depending on what Facebook finds should be accessible to whom. You can read more about it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

For your purpose of showing your group's events on a web page, you may have to do a work around. You will have to create your own Access Token and hard code it. Obviously you should not do that in Javascript but user PHP API

Comment: To add to that...you currently need read_stream as a permission to get most posts from a group. You can get an access token from the API graph tool to see this work. To bad the access token only works for 2hrs or 60 days if you extend it on website applications. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.1

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way that doesn't require users to log into Facebook would be to

1. Create a [Facebook App](https://developers.facebook.com/)
2. Use the following code to retrieve the events of
3. Modify AJAX to refer to new code file (e.g. facebookEvents.php)

Code below to go on your server

```
<?php
    # facebookEvents.php

    $FacebookID = '';
    $APP_ID='';
    $APP_SECRET='';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print_r(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$FacebookID/events?access_token=$APP_ID|$APP_SECRET"));
?>
```

App ID and App Secret available from the App Dashboard
[image: Facebook App ID and App Secret]